# Change app language from settings on Android using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

In the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/) it says:

> On newer Android and iOS versions, app language can be set per app, so you usually don't need to build a custom UI to allow users to change the current locale inside of your app

In the section [Translating app metadata](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#translating-app-metadata) it is described how you can add `locales` to you `app.json`. After doing so, iOS shows the locales in iOS Settings app.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true
      }
    },
    "locales": {
      "ja": "./languages/japanese.json"
    }
  }
}
```

However, the language selection does not show app in the App Language page in Android the Settings App. How do I enable this feature on Android?

Comment: You need Android 13 or newer. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages.